Drinfeld centres and formal moduli problems
If $\mathcal{P}$ is a sufficiently nice operad, then by [Higher Algebra, 5.3] you can form its centre:
$$\mathcal{Z}_{\mathcal{P}}\ :\ \mathcal{P}\text{-Alg}\ \to\ \mathbf{E}_1\text{-Alg}(\mathcal{P}\text{-Alg}).$$
Next, if $\mathcal{Q}$ is a sufficiently nice operad, any $\mathcal{Q}$-formal moduli problem as in [Operadic deformation theory, 3.3] is uniquely specified by its shifted tangent complex, which is a $\mathcal{Q}^!=\text{KD}(\mathcal{Q})[-1]$-algebra,
$$\text{FMP}_\mathcal{Q}\ \stackrel{\sim}{\to}\ \mathcal{Q}^!\text{-Alg} \hspace{15mm}F\ \mapsto \ T_{\mathcal{O},F}.$$
Studying deformations of $B\in\mathcal{Q}\text{-Alg}$ over Artin $\mathcal{Q}$-algebras gives a formal moduli problem $\text{Def}_B$.
Question: If $\mathcal{O}$ is a sufficiently nice operad and $C\in \mathcal{O}\text{-Alg}$, what is the relation between

The $\mathbf{E}_1\otimes\mathcal{O}$-algebra $\mathcal{Z}_\mathcal{O}(C)$,
The $\mathcal{O}^!$-algebra $T_{\mathcal{O},\text{Def}_C}$?


If you give an answer, please check the $\mathcal{O}=\mathbf{E}_1$ case, where the first is $\text{HC}^*(C,C)$ and the second is I think also $\text{HC}^*(C,C)$ (though this might be wrong).

There's actually a slight mismatch even in the $E_1$ case, as the tangent complex is the truncated Hochschild complex (built from $\mathrm{Hom}(C^{\otimes n},C)$ for $n \ge 1$), so it's the kernel of the map from the centre to the original algebra. Something similar happens for $E_n$-algebras ($n$ finite). Without self-duality of the operad, there doesn't seem much to say.

Actually, it's even worse than that: the shifted tangent complex they use corresponds to Hochschild cohomology with coefficients in the residue field, not in $C$ itself.

@JonPridham Ah, thanks! Just one final check that my question is negative if $\mathcal{O}$ is not self-dual: in that case  $\mathcal{Z}_\mathcal{O}(C)$ says nothing about the $\mathcal{O}$-deformation theory of $C$?

(Because I'd imagine that if the answer is there is some relation, then $\mathcal{Z}$ and $T$ should be related somehow, if not by being equal, and if the answer is there's no relation to deformations then I'm happy that 1 and 2 are unrelated unless the operad is self-dual)

For the commutative operad, the centre is just the algebra itself, and so the kernel is $0$. Hard to imagine a general statement relating that to deformations. The centre also depends heavily on the operad having a Hopf operad structure.
